# Transformations not importing in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-livedata-transformations

I am trying to add currency symbol with the cost using Transformations of Live Data object, but it is not importing.

```
private val _price = MutableLiveData<Double>()
val price: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_price) {
   NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(it)
}
```

Please debug

Comment: Which version of the androidx.lifecycle library are you using? If it's 2.6.0 or newer then you should replace `Transformations.map(_price) { }` with `_price.map { }`. See [the changelog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.6.0) for version 2.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `androidx.lifecycle` with 2.6.0 or newer version then you should use the following code.

**Your Example**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.map

private val _price = MutableLiveData<Double>()
val price: LiveData<String> = _price.map("${NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(_price)}")
```

**My Example**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.map

class PagerViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _index = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val mPosition: LiveData<Int> = _index.map{ it }
    fun setIndex(index: Int) {
        _index.value = index
    }
}
```